# Alloc initWithString vs retain

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

Is there any difference *from Memory perspective* between the following two lines

```
NSString *dbFilePath =[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:dbName ofType:nil]];
```

and

```
  NSString *dbFilePath =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:dbName ofType:nil] retain];
```

"[NSString alloc]initWithString:" or just "retain"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically, there is no difference. However, in the first case, you temporarily have one more `NSString` object existing than in the second case, i.e. the object returned by `pathForResource` which will be autoreleased shortly after, *and* it's surviving copy.

In the second case, no copy is made. Instead, the object returned by `pathForResource` is retained directly. One object less at peak time.

I find the second piece of code more straightforward.

However, I wonder why you retain something that is referenced from the stack. I would expect `dbFilePath` instead to be something more persistent, like a member variable.

Comment: The rule about covenience constructors returning autoreleased objects is an outmoded construct from MRC.  All objects returned through constructors are implicitly strong, your storage of them is what matters.

Comment: Thanks, @CodaFi. The answer is from someone who lives in the MRC world.

Comment: Are you saying you lifted this answer from somewhere else on the site, or are you referring to yourself ;)

Comment: Referring to myself. But you got me curious, maybe you can elaborate on your comment. The question looked to me like MRC related.

Comment: You probably don't have to worry about it in this particular case, but  in general, you should `-copy` objects with value-type semantics rather than `-retain` them when you "take ownership" of them.  You could have been returned an `NSMutableString` which might be subsequently mutated by the object that returned it to you. Immutable objects implement `-copyWithZone:` by calling `retain` so that a copy is made only if it's necessary.